# Cross-domain ajax call from a page with external iframe

Tags: javascript, ajax, webkit, cross-domain

I was using successfully a cross-request ajax call using jquery, setting its `$.support.cors = true` and sending an appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from the server. It all worked well till I included an Iframe on the page with a page hosted on yet another server.

Soon the error message "Origin *** is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." showed up again. Seems like the inclusion of the iframe makes the containing page appear like belonging to a different domain. Is this possible? Is this a know behavior (or bug) of webkit? (I'm experiencing this with Safari and Chrome, but with Firefox it works fine)? Is there any workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that the inclusion of the `iframe` causes your once-working AJAX call to fail? Have you considered using JSONP instead of CORS?

Comment: This is not possible; inclusion of nested iframes should have no effect on AJAX calls, with or without CORS. Can you provide a link with a simplified test case that demonstrates the error?

Comment: Can you provide a sample HTML file that reproduces the issue?